# sqLite error when using update statement

Tags: java, sqlite

I am busy using a SQLite database with a java application and after updating the database successfully I get the following error

> org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement@4e1c6f

Below is my update code

```
            PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE highLeaker SET " + cyc + " = "
                    + dataArray[3] + " , "
                    + "gasSurveyOperator" + " = "
                    + dataArray[1] + " , "
                    + "gasSurveySerial" + " = "
                    + dataArray[2] + " , "
                    + "loss" + " = "
                    + dataArray[4] + " , "
                    + "comment" + " = "
                    + dataArray[5] + " , "
                    + "cycle" + " = '"
                    + cycleT + "' , "
                    + "date" + " = "
                    + dataArray[6]
                    + " WHERE leakerID = " + dataArray[0]+";");
            System.out.println(update);
            update.executeUpdate();

            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a `JDBC4PreparedStatement` object... you just need to *use* it properly instead of dumping it to System.out. Also, you're showing it *before* actually updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

You printed out the object. Also, I would highly recommend using place holders instead when executing SQL queries.